# Can I use GIT with Visual Studio 2013 without using TFS?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, tfs

*Disclaimer: I'm really new to Visual Studio. I know how to use and set up GIT, just not though Visual Studio.*

I need to work with a team on a project, and we want to use GIT as a version control system. With GIT what I would do it set up a remote repository on one of our servers, and we would push and pull from the repository I created. However, when I try to connect Visual Studio 2013 with my GIT created remote repository it throws a number of errors at me. I've been searching online and everything that mentions Visual Studio 2013 with GIT seems to assume I'm going to put my remote repository on a Team Foundation Server, either hosted my Microsoft or set up on my own server.

The problem is, that this project is on a pretty tight budget, and the original programmer didn't account for the cost of TFS. Is it possible to use Visual Studio's built in GIT features to work with a team, but without a TFS set up somewhere?

**edit: My manager doesn't want to use any sort of cloud hosting service, so I need to be able to store the remote repository on one of my servers.**

Comment: Hosted TFS is free (for small teams), but Visual Studio isn't restricted to using the included source control clients - you can download others

Comment: Can you give me some tips, or even a how-to online, on setting up a remote repository for GIT with Visual Studio without having to set up a tfs? It doesn't seem to like connecting to the pure GIT create repository I've already made.

Comment: [SO] is not a tutorial: there are plenty of those online. Also note where the source repository in the example screen shot in the second link on my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't meaning to ask for a tutorial. I've edited my question because I didn't mention that my manager doesn't want to use any cloud based services. I've been searching online for tutorials or answers already. And I can't find an answer to whether I can create a remote repository to use GIT with Visual Studio without using either cloud based services or TFS. Is the answer to this still 'Yes'?

Comment: Just set up a repository on GitHub, GitLab, etc for testing purposes. As soon as you clone your repository on your local machine you will be able to see this repository in the Team Explorer in the same way you see repositories located on a TFS. If your manager does not allow a cloud service you can set up your own GitLab server, which is really similar to GitHub.

Comment: You can put a Git repository on a file share via a mapped drive (with a little care to get the Windows style path working: lots of backslashes :-)) and then clone to your workspace. (But I don't have any examples to hand here.)

Answer (score 5):

*[Use Visual Studio with Git](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850437.aspx)*

> […]or on a third-party service such as GitHub or Bitbucket.

More specifically: *[Clone a remote Git repository from a third-party service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850445.aspx#remote_3rd_party_connect_clone)*.

EDIT: Above link is broken. Similar information is available here: [*Clone a third-party Git repository to your dev machine*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/02/06/set-up-connect-and-publish-using-visual-studio-with-git.aspx#clone-3rd-party)

Comment: @PhilippMichalski I've put in an alternative (to an MSDN blog rather than MSDN itself; feel free to edit if you can find the new MSDN page).